# split string on any special character using python

Tags: python, python-3.x

currently I can have many dynamic separators in string like

```
new_123_12313131
new$123$12313131
new#123#12313131
```

etc etc . I just want to check if there is a special character in string then just get value after last separator like in this example just want   **12313131**

Comment: define "special"

Comment: @JacobIRR for example special characters like  these  `:/.=[$`   . is there any python built in function exist to check these ?

Comment: Yes, but I see that you also exclude `new` from the string. Do you want only numbers as your end result (with no strings OR special characters)?

Comment: @JacobIRR  yes I just need last integer part of string which is after last special character basically  everytime .

Comment: Try this - ```last = s.split('#')[-1]```  last is your ans.;  just replace the *sep* in the *spit()*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python supplies what seems to be what you consider "special" characters using the string library as [`string.punctuation`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#string.punctuation). Which are these characters:

```
!"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~
```

Using that in conjunction with the `re` module you can do this:

```
from string import punctuation
import re

re.split(f"[{punctuation}]", my_string)
```

`my_string` being the string you want to split.

Results for your examples

```
['new', '123', '12313131']
```

To get just digits you can use:

```
re.split("\d", my_string)
```

Results:

```
['123', '12313131']
```

Comment: hi sir thanks for answer . but from this I won't be able to check if there is special character in string or not . as It will return whole string in case of  for example new13123123123

Comment: use `re.search` or `re.findall` instead of split then. Also, it doesn't return the whole string but only the non special chars as shown in the answer

Answer (score 1):

This is a good use case for `isdigit()`:

```
l = [
'new_123_12313131',
'new$123$12313131',
'new#123#12313131',
]

output = []
for s in l:
    temp = ''
    for char in s:
        if char.isdigit():
            temp += char
    output.append(temp)        

print(output)
```

**Result**: ['12312313131', '12312313131', '12312313131']

Comment: thanks sir for reply . but there is case I mentioned in my question  `I just want to check if there is a special character in string` . So how I will be so sure that there is a special character and not a character which stopped my count ? as I will stop on special character

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you define 'special character' as anything thats not alphanumeric, you can use the `str.isalnum()` function to determine the first special character and leverage it something like this:

```
def split_non_special(input) -> str:
    """
    Find first special character starting from the end and get the last piece
    """
    for i in reversed(input):
        if not i.isalnum():
            return input.split(i)[-1] # return as soon as a separator is found
    return '' # no separator found

# inputs = ['new_123_12313131', 'new$123$12313131', 'new#123#12313131', 'eefwfwrfwfwf3243']
# outputs = [split_non_special(input) for input in inputs]
# ['12313131', '12313131', '12313131', ''] # outputs
```

Answer (score 1):

> just get value after last separator

the more obvious way is using `re.findall`:

```
from re import findall

findall(r'\d+$',text)  # ['12313131']
```